# How do I resolve: TypeError: int() takes exactly 5 arguments (4 given)

Tags: python

I am editing a part of [conversation.py](https://github.com/jasperproject/jasper-client/blob/master/client/conversation.py) which is a part Jasper voice recognition software to add sound effects. The part of the code I am concerned with is init(). I am using code and trying to replicate *self.speaker = speaker* from [mic.py](https://github.com/jasperproject/jasper-client/blob/master/client/mic.py)

ORIGINAL CODE:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8-*-
import logging
from notifier import Notifier
from brain import Brain


class Conversation(object):

    def __init__(self, persona, mic, profile):
        self._logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        self.persona = persona
        self.mic = mic
        self.profile = profile
        self.brain = Brain(mic, profile)
        self.notifier = Notifier(profile)

    def handleForever(self):
        """
        Delegates user input to the handling function when activated.
        """
        self._logger.info("Starting to handle conversation with keyword '%s'.",
                          self.persona)
        while True:
            # Print notifications until empty
            notifications = self.notifier.getAllNotifications()
            for notif in notifications:
                self._logger.info("Received notification: '%s'", str(notif))

            self._logger.debug("Started listening for keyword '%s'",
                               self.persona)
            threshold, transcribed = self.mic.passiveListen(self.persona)
            self._logger.debug("Stopped listening for keyword '%s'",
                               self.persona)

            if not transcribed or not threshold:
                self._logger.info("Nothing has been said or transcribed.")
                continue
            self._logger.info("Keyword '%s' has been said!", self.persona)

            self._logger.debug("Started to listen actively with threshold: %r",
                               threshold)
            input = self.mic.activeListenToAllOptions(threshold)
            self._logger.debug("Stopped to listen actively with threshold: %r",
                               threshold)

            if input:
                self.brain.query(input)
            else:
                self.mic.say("Pardon?")
```

EDITED CODE:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8-*-
import logging
from notifier import Notifier
from brain import Brain


class Conversation(object):

    def __init__(self, speaker, persona, mic, profile):
        self._logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        self.speaker = speaker  #ADDED LINE
        self.persona = persona
        self.mic = mic
        self.profile = profile
        self.brain = Brain(mic, profile)
        self.notifier = Notifier(profile)

    def handleForever(self):
        """
        Delegates user input to the handling function when activated.
        """
        self._logger.info("Starting to handle conversation with keyword '%s'.",
                          self.persona)
        while True:
            # Print notifications until empty
            notifications = self.notifier.getAllNotifications()
            for notif in notifications:
                self._logger.info("Received notification: '%s'", str(notif))

            self._logger.debug("Started listening for keyword '%s'",
                               self.persona)
            threshold, transcribed = self.mic.passiveListen(self.persona)
            self._logger.debug("Stopped listening for keyword '%s'",
                               self.persona)

            if not transcribed or not threshold:
                self._logger.info("Nothing has been said or transcribed.")
                continue
            self._logger.info("Keyword '%s' has been said!", self.persona)

            self._logger.debug("Started to listen actively with threshold: %r",
                               threshold)
            input = self.mic.activeListenToAllOptions(threshold)
            self._logger.debug("Stopped to listen actively with threshold: %r",
                               threshold)

            if input:
                self.brain.query(input)
            else:
                self.speaker.play(jasperpath.data('audio', 'SpeechMis.wav')) #ADDED LINE
                self.mic.say("Pardon?")
```

When I run the Jasper software that includes this modified code I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/jasper/jasper.py", line 151, in <module>
    app.run()
  File "/home/pi/jasper/jasper.py", line 120, in run
    conversation = Conversation("JASPER", self.mic, self.config)
TypeError: int() takes exactly 5 arguments (4 given)
```

I have looked at other TypeError questions and have read the code carefully. I still don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

```
class Conversation(object):
    def __init__(self, speaker, persona, mic, profile):

...

conversation = Conversation("JASPER", self.mic, self.config)
```

You modified `Conversation.__init__` signature and now it expects 4 arguments (`speaker`, `persona`, `mic`, `profile`), yet the calling code still provides values for only the first 3.

In order to modify the class while not breaking existing code, add the new argument to the end and use default value:

```
class Conversation(object):
    def __init__(self, persona, mic, profile, speaker=None):
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I will try that.

Comment: Now when I run the code I get AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'play'